# 3D Touch Application Shortcut Sorting

Tags: ios, ios9, xcode7, 3dtouch

I implemented 3D touch application shortcuts via the info.plist (static entries) and then the code implementation, all works fine.  However, I cannot seem to get the sort of the shortcuts to persist.  I tried drag/drop in Xcode 7.1 to reorder them and initially it looked fine but now again they are sorted opposite.

How are application shortcuts sorted? If any?

I'm using an iPhone 6S with iOS 9.1.

Answer (score 1):

The order is plist order.  What threw me off is whether the menu opens up or down depending on where your application icon exists.  It will order in plist order starting from the application icon and then outwards from there.